# Mouse Over - Show MYSQL Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

So far, I have the following code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "root";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "test_db";
$bd             = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database
$location       = "";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assets natural join loc_admin natural join id_info WHERE assets.id_location LIKE '$location%'");

echo '<table border=1px>';  // opening table tag
echo'<th>ID</th><th>ID_Location</th><th>Room</th><th>Device Type</th><th>Model</th><th>Version</th><th>Firmware</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Tech_Name</th>'; //table headers

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   // we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
   echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
   echo '<td>'.$data['idassets'].'</td><td>'.$data['id_location'].'</td><td>'.$data['room_number'].'</td><td>'.$data['device'].'</td><td>'.$data['model'].'</td><td>'.$data['version'].'</td><td>'.$data['firmware'].'</td><td>'.$data['manufacturer'].'</td><td>'.$data['tech_name'].'</td>'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
   echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}

echo '</table>';  //closing table tag


?>
```

Works great -- I can display all my info in each of the 3 tables.

For now, I am only displaying the above, BUT I would like to get a mouse over to display the data (Site information ) in a db called id_info and in there are rows with location_name, location_email etc WHEN i hover the mouse of the initial id_location. I am trying find out simple  ways of doing it. thanks for the help. It took me awhile just to get to this point of displaying data and setting up the relationships b/t all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool tip to display the results from database on mouse over

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title=" <?php echo $data['location_name'].$data['location_email'];?> " > link </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need some Ajax script which prints directly those info in an hover box. As far as i know, there's no PHP function doing what you ask.

Comment: unluckily no. Anyway, this sad function of giving downvotes convinced me to not participate anymore to this site.

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work,

i used the below url. works really well

```
http://hscripts.com/tutorials/html/tooltip.php
```